# Sandbox to test stack exchange flavoured markdown or prepare posts prior to publication.

Tags: discussion

As per [Jeff's suggestion in this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/can-we-get-a-test-stackoverflow-com#comment1215_758):

You can use this question as a formatting sandbox. You can

- post any answers to this question
- post comments to this question or its answers
- test suspected bugs with the editor

Beware that since the [changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) in December 2010, and [the inline hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) added March 2011, **no syntax highlighting is applied unless the question's tags or an inline hint enable it**. So, to test highlighting here in the sandbox:

1. On the start of a line, [specify a language inline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) using `<!-- language: lang -->` hints, and indent the code 4 spaces as usual. There is a [full list of hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109) (scroll down a little).

   ```
   <!-- language: lang-html -->

       While not hinted otherwise: <html></html> source <b>goes</b> "here".

   <!-- language: lang-js -->

       var a = 3;
       while (not (a > 0)) {
           alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
       }
   ```
2. Or:

   - Save your post.
   - Use something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (Firefox), [Web Inspector](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector) (Safari, Chrome) or [Developer Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/07/improved-productivity-through-internet-explorer-8-developer-tools.aspx) (Internet Explorer 8) to edit the resulting HTML. To open Chrome Dev Tools, press <kbd>F12</kbd>
   - Find the `<pre>` element and add the attribute `class="prettyprint"`, or change it into something more specific, like `class="lang-vb prettyprint"`.
   - Run the following in the location bar: `javascript:prettyPrint();`

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind we can turn this in a general SE sandbox for everyone.

Comment: It's just what I need. I could not take off the discussion tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Roll the ball!]
Works using Markdown...

[image]
...and plain HTML

^---- Animated SVG!

---

Chrome's throbbers:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Formatting you possibly didn't know about:

`[meta-tag:status-declined]` = [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
`[meta-tag:status-completed]` = [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

- http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html
- [Test1](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [Test2](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [NoAsterisk](http://web.archive.org/web//http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [NoColon](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http//java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [NoAsteriskNoColonNoHttp](http://web.archive.org/web///java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [Properlink?](http://web.archive.org/web/http:/java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [Tor Link](https://dppmfxaacucguzpc.onion/)

M̵̳̙͔̟̱͕̓̀̄̉̅ͧ̋͊͌͑́͌ͪ̒̿̀̚a͔̟̝͔ͥ̈́̏ͮͯ̇͆̊̒ͦͦ͘͢͜y̵̴̢͕̝̩̱͈͕̼̣͕̟̌͗̾ͤ̎͌̄ͣͨ͊ͬb̡̯̰̪̜͙̟̝̠͚̜̥̙̤̃ͨ̋̒̒̊ͧͤ͐̓͋̌̾̇̔̈́̀́͡͠e̵ͯͪ̿̿̂̄ͫ̃҉͏͎̣̹̱̜͉̦̞̪̘̠̝̝͍̼̜̖̥̭͟ ̣̞͙͚̝̰̞̹̗̲̣͙͍͍̀̓͊̂̋ͣ̏̑̍̊͌ͩ͐̎̀ͣͣ̚͟ͅh̛͋̏̍̆ͤ͛͐ͨ̌̋ͤ̎̂ͨ̂̓̑̚̕͟͏̻̣͖̖͚͚͓̲̼̪ȁ̔̅̿͐̑͡͏̝͓̮͚̘̦̰͚͎͔͉͚̮̠̕͜ͅṱ̱̼̖̓̂ͭ̏̅͂ͥ͌ͯ͌͠sͪ̓ͪ̄̌̓ͧ͋͐ͬ̅̑҉̨̪̬͎͍̥̬?̡̮̳͙͓͔̹̘̹͓̘̻̦̣͎̫̐ͤ̐͛́͝ ̧̦̼̘͕̪̠̙͖̦̯̦̘͉͈͕͔̘̻̲͑ͨ̊̈́̐ͫ͐̌ͯ̀͘͝Ḩ̷̸̸̹͉̩̜̹̞ͯ̃̃ͧͬͨ̌̀̾̐̈̇ͧ͛̃͐̀ͦ͞A̴̦̗̬̠͙̭͉̟̺͇̭̰͔͕̯̅̃͋ͪ̈́̉̓̌ͯ̈́͆̋̀ͤ̇̂̿̈́̂͡͡Ṱ̲͎͉̣̳̺̱̜̦̬͕̣͉͇͊̌ͥ͐͒̈́̓́ͥ́́̋͂̅ͬ̆͗ͥ̕͢͡S̍ͧ͗̒͗̂̈ͬ͊̚̚͢͏̗̣̳ͅ!̶̨̡͇͚̙͚̭̱̣̲̳̤̞̫̗̣̦̮̖̞͒͆̿̄͑̃̎͡

Answer (score 0):

(Empty for use by anyone as a sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

Testing [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/226837).

```
While not hinted otherwise: <html></html> source <b>goes</b> "here".
```

```
var a = 3;
while (not (a > 0)) {
    alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this highlighting work?

```
While not hinted otherwise: <html></html> source <b>goes</b> "here".
```

```
var a = 3;
while (not (a > 0)) {
    alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
}
```